# Sequelize is transforming my string field to a number if the contents represent a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

My string field is getting cast to a number if the contents of the field is a number. For example, if I have store the text `11` in the field `Table.value`, and I execute the following code:

```
let Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite://dbName', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: './service/data.db'
});

var Table = sequelize.define('Table', {
    value: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

Table.findAll().then(results => {
    console.log(results[0].value, typeof results[0].value);
});
```

... the result will be 11 'number'. If I change that same field to 11a, then it returns the correct type (STRING).

This seems like a bug to me (it should return as a STRING because that's how I defined it). Doesn't seem like anyone has encountered this issue from Sequelize's Issue tracker, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: What is the actual column type that Sequelize uses in the table definition?

Comment: So I now realize where it went wrong! sqlite3 is very forgiving with the data types. You can even specify a completely false one, i.e. blahblahblah. When you provide a non-existent data-type, sqlite3/sequelize will try to determine it for you. So if you have a numeric string, i.e. `11`, `Model.find` will return it as a number.